# Array and pointers in c++ trying to understand the meaning of address of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c-strings

I am trying to get a grasp of the meaning of the address of an array.

I wrote the following code to try to understand the meaning, but I could not grasp it:

```cpp
char d [] {"Ashish"};

std::cout << d <<std::endl;

std::cout <<&d <<std::endl;

std::cout <<&d[0] <<std::endl;

std::cout <<(void*)&d[0] <<std::endl;
```

What will the output be for each statement? Why is the output for the 2nd and 4th statements the same?

Comment: The address of an "array" is the same address as the address of its first element. However note that in current C++ there is hardly ever a need to work with "C" style arrays like that anymore.  Also using the "C" style `(void*)` is hardly ever used in C++ either.

Comment: This becomes extra confusing when you use an array of `char`, because arrays off `char` are magic. Start out with an array of `int`; once you understand that you can look at the complications that `char` introduces.

Comment: Nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: The address of any object is the address of its first byte. Consequently, the address of any object is the same as the address of its first subobject.

Comment: Great code, in my opinion, the fact that is raised questions is the evidence of it.   

I assume you've already did the same four printing statements with `const char *`, now you can also compare it to `std::array`, its manual analog (a structure containing an array as its only element), and `std::string`. And, as suggested, do the same with `int` instead of `char` too (using a vector of ints instead of `std::string`). Then you can try passing all these objects to functions and return them from functions while avoiding dangling. Note the different address values, too.

Answer (score 6):

> `std::cout << d <<std::endl;`

Here the array decays into a pointer (a `char*`) to its first element. Since there is an `operator<<` overload taking a `const char*` in order to be able to print C strings, the string `Ashish` is printed.

> `std::cout << &d <<std::endl;`

Here you take the address of the array to form a pointer to a `char[7]`. There is no specific `operator<<` overload for that but there is a fallback overload for `void*` which will be used to print the address.

> `std::cout << &d[0] <<std::endl;`

Here you form a pointer to the first element in the array. Again, this is a `char*` and the same `operator<<` as in the first case will be used.

> `std::cout << (void*)&d[0] <<std::endl;`

Here you form a pointer to the first element in the array but cast it to `void*` so the `operator<<` overload used in the second case will be used here too.